# hantronix HDM24216L-2-L3ES pinout

Tags: lcd, pinout, character-lcd

I am looking for the pinout on a hantronix HDM24216L-2-L3ES
24x1 LCD. I found the datasheet:
http://www.hantronix.com/files/data/1278557021char-comm.pdf
but I cant determine what the pinout is. Can someone help me find the pinout for this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same page you got that datasheet from has another datasheet with the pin connections: http://www.hantronix.com/files/data/127855702124216l2.pdf You just had to select the data sheet and not the full spec. That full spec is also like, 10% of a full spec. Pretty sad documentation availability.